# Saving NSMutableDictionary into plist issue

Tags: iphone, ios, plist, nsmutabledictionary, ios5.1

I'm getting a weird behavior when testing my app on a device. This is the function I'm using to update values for keys, which works smoothly on my iphone simulator. Very well indeed. However the nslog on line 6 of plist returns null on device. Do you have any ideas about why and what I am doing wrong? thank you in advance

```
-(void) updateData:(int)contacto campo:(int)campo {

    NSString *rootPath = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *plistPath = [rootPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Data.plist"];

    NSMutableDictionary *plistDict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:plistPath];
    NSLog(@"%@",plistDict);

    switch (campo) {
        case 0:         
            veterinarioID = contacto;
            [plistDict setValue:[NSNumber numberWithInt:veterinarioID] forKey:@"veterinario"];
            NSLog(@"%d",veterinarioID);
            break;
        case 1:
            peluqueriaID = contacto;
            [plistDict setValue:[NSNumber numberWithInt:peluqueriaID] forKey:@"peluqueria"];
            NSLog(@"%d",peluqueriaID);

            break;
        case 2:
            residenciaID = contacto;
            [plistDict setValue:[NSNumber numberWithInt:residenciaID] forKey:@"residencia"];
            NSLog(@"%d",residenciaID);
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
    [plistDict writeToFile:plistPath atomically: YES];

}
```

Comment: put plistPath to console

Comment: does the file at `plistPath` actually exist on the device?

Comment: This is the console output for plistPath: 

2012-09-22 15:14:05.710 testAPP[6500:12503] /Users/Samuel/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/5.1/Applications/FC9C7FC7-BAFB-4EBC-95FC-D9D256E58EA5/Documents/Data.plist

Comment: and console for device's plistPath: 
2012-09-22 15:16:38.142 testAPP[4922:707] /var/mobile/Applications/EEB375D7-E39B-4456-9F19-29AEC9401A79/Documents/Data.plist

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My guess is that your code has evolved over time, and that you have had an existing dictionary in the simulator for a long time. Thus the file has been around for a long time there.

On the device now, if the file is not there, the dictionary is nil, and noting gets saved ever.

Change your code to the following and I believe the problem will be fixed:

```
NSMutableDictionary *plistDict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:plistPath];
if(!plistDict) plistDict = [NSMutableDictionary new]; // I like using 'new'
NSLog(@"%@",plistDict);
```

Comment: David, your "new" approach did the trick. Thanks for your help ;)